# Web fonts in Internet Explorer revert after page finishes loading

Tags: css, internet-explorer, webfonts

I'm running into a small issue with a site I'm working on. I'm using the font services from [Fonts.com](http://www.fonts.com) to serve up the CSS and web fonts I use on the site, and everything works well except in Internet. The page appears to render with the fonts correctly in place, but when the loading is complete, IE reverts back to the default font.

Here's a sample of the CSS:

```
@font-face{
    font-family:"HelveticaNeueW02-55Roma";
    src:url("/d/0b3a3fca-0fad-402b-bd38-fdcbad1ef776.eot?d44f19a684109620e484167aa390e81872e11b421ef14b20f5dda8683b7716e34431bd7031a61bffb8b38558710357d5ed49d8a7dcd4f490bf2bc9922040a50d670eaafb6e334fcf61c48a10483015d48bd9b9cb074a09c71c211940cb0c60886a2d42510bad7eced9195baae7bedb11ccbdb0d618032faccca0c925a83db7aac01d0bae4b090b6680179034630a36491101451eadad15f77b41f406d48f0f3592bf2731964d594bed634b405df69863674a8be20883212f56ec396a14e1cc983ae5cf8a554298e7314350fa96b78a363d2b4ccfc8ff090d5c8ce49e47d02bc317e0334f5b6efa484026&projectId=215db553-2cf6-4cbb-a5fd-6a4b7d7b8bac") format("eot");
}

@font-face{
    font-family:"HelveticaNeueW02-55Roma";
    src:url("/d/0b3a3fca-0fad-402b-bd38-fdcbad1ef776.eot?d44f19a684109620e484167aa390e81872e11b421ef14b20f5dda8683b7716e34431bd7031a61bffb8b38558710357d5ed49d8a7dcd4f490bf2bc9922040a50d670eaafb6e334fcf61c48a10483015d48bd9b9cb074a09c71c211940cb0c60886a2d42510bad7eced9195baae7bedb11ccbdb0d618032faccca0c925a83db7aac01d0bae4b090b6680179034630a36491101451eadad15f77b41f406d48f0f3592bf2731964d594bed634b405df69863674a8be20883212f56ec396a14e1cc983ae5cf8a554298e7314350fa96b78a363d2b4ccfc8ff090d5c8ce49e47d02bc317e0334f5b6efa484026&projectId=215db553-2cf6-4cbb-a5fd-6a4b7d7b8bac");
    src:url("/d/d5af76d8-a90b-4527-b3a3-182207cc3250.woff?d44f19a684109620e484167aa390e81872e11b421ef14b20f5dda8683b7716e34431bd7031a61bffb8b38558710357d5ed49d8a7dcd4f490bf2bc9922040a50d670eaafb6e334fcf61c48a10483015d48bd9b9cb074a09c71c211940cb0c60886a2d42510bad7eced9195baae7bedb11ccbdb0d618032faccca0c925a83db7aac01d0bae4b090b6680179034630a36491101451eadad15f77b41f406d48f0f3592bf2731964d594bed634b405df69863674a8be20883212f56ec396a14e1cc983ae5cf8a554298e7314350fa96b78a363d2b4ccfc8ff090d5c8ce49e47d02bc317e0334f5b6efa484026&projectId=215db553-2cf6-4cbb-a5fd-6a4b7d7b8bac") format("woff"),url("/d/1d238354-d156-4dde-89ea-4770ef04b9f9.ttf?d44f19a684109620e484167aa390e81872e11b421ef14b20f5dda8683b7716e34431bd7031a61bffb8b38558710357d5ed49d8a7dcd4f490bf2bc9922040a50d670eaafb6e334fcf61c48a10483015d48bd9b9cb074a09c71c211940cb0c60886a2d42510bad7eced9195baae7bedb11ccbdb0d618032faccca0c925a83db7aac01d0bae4b090b6680179034630a36491101451eadad15f77b41f406d48f0f3592bf2731964d594bed634b405df69863674a8be20883212f56ec396a14e1cc983ae5cf8a554298e7314350fa96b78a363d2b4ccfc8ff090d5c8ce49e47d02bc317e0334f5b6efa484026&projectId=215db553-2cf6-4cbb-a5fd-6a4b7d7b8bac") format("truetype"),url("/d/b68875cb-14a9-472e-8177-0247605124d7.svg?d44f19a684109620e484167aa390e81872e11b421ef14b20f5dda8683b7716e34431bd7031a61bffb8b38558710357d5ed49d8a7dcd4f490bf2bc9922040a50d670eaafb6e334fcf61c48a10483015d48bd9b9cb074a09c71c211940cb0c60886a2d42510bad7eced9195baae7bedb11ccbdb0d618032faccca0c925a83db7aac01d0bae4b090b6680179034630a36491101451eadad15f77b41f406d48f0f3592bf2731964d594bed634b405df69863674a8be20883212f56ec396a14e1cc983ae5cf8a554298e7314350fa96b78a363d2b4ccfc8ff090d5c8ce49e47d02bc317e0334f5b6efa484026&projectId=215db553-2cf6-4cbb-a5fd-6a4b7d7b8bac#b68875cb-14a9-472e-8177-0247605124d7") format("svg");
}
```

and typical use cases:

```
body {
    font-family: "DIN Next W02 Cond";
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
}


p {
    font-family: "HelveticaNeueW02-55Roma";
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

The [wide font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQZ5v.png) is what displays after the page finishes loading, while the [narrow font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZQ8c.png) (the correct font) is displayed during page load.

Is there an easy fix? Fonts.com provides a web portal to specify the fonts in the CSS, which they serve from their servers - so I can't easily edit that. I can edit the `font-family` property for elements using the web fonts, though. If any more information is needed, I'll provide it where possible.

Edit: this is *not* a flash of unstyled content, it renders properly from what is presumably the cache, then (upon re-downloading the file) *discards* the custom font and replaces it with a default font when the page is done loading. It's the reverse of what I and others are expecting, hence posting here for a fix.

Comment: In the F12 Tools Console, do you see any warnings? Is there a repro URL?

Answer (score 0):

the flicker you see is fouc or fout, im assuming your using IE9, it'll will display text in a default font while the web font loads — even in compatibility mode.

@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSansLight';
    src: url('OpenSans-Light-webfont.eot');
    src: url('OpenSans-Light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('OpenSans-Light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('OpenSans-Light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('OpenSans-Light-webfont.svg#OpenSansLight') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

that's the best way to get @font-face cross-browser. if you need those files created, head over to fontsquirrel.com

font loader is used by typekit and google fonts to fix the flash; i'm not sure if you'll have to tweak it for your code, but you can snag it on github https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader

Comment: The problem is so strange it's hard to word properly. It's not that I'm trying to avoid FOUT, it's that the fonts load immediately (presumably from cache), then *stop* being used shortly after the files are re-downloaded. It's the opposite of displaying default until the custom is ready - it displays custom until the page loads, then discards the custom style and replaces it with the default text.

Comment: are you declaring them in the style i showed or the one you showed? show us your code dude.

Comment: I can't easily change the CSS, since that's provided directly by fonts.com (I could spoof it, but that would make it very difficult to change later). I added a pair of typical use cases to the original post. Both of the code snippets are directly from CSS served on the page.

Comment: you can't change the css, as in you are pulling in their styles/files via a link element?

Comment: Yes. `<link href="http://fast.fonts.com/cssapi/215db553-2cf6-4cbb-a5fd-6a4b7d7b8bac.css" rel="stylesheet">` is the copy/pasted snippet they give to put in the `<head>` element.

Comment: idk man. that sucks...i guess you're paying? hit up their admins and see if/why they aren't using @font-squirrel syntax? they should be up to speed

Comment: I'm having the same issue in IE7 + 8. And we're hosting our own fonts. The webfont displays correctly while the page is loading, then reverts to whatever's next in the font stack. I'll let you know if I figure out what's causing it.

Answer (score 0):

So for me, it was a local issue.

When we deployed to our staging server, **the fonts displayed correctly in IE 7 and 8** .

Still don't know why they're not showing up locally, but at least it works in production.

Answer (score 0):

My fonts display properly in IE8 locally. Also works in chrome and FF.

The fonts fail in production. I'm using fontawesome for bootstrap twitter.

I find that once the page is loaded, If I select the entire page then all the loaded fonts appear. So they are there, but IE8 disregards once the page is loaded.
 I've checked quirks mode and all other combinations.

It's definitely a "when loaded" to "speed of load" in "relation to other CSS" issue.
Re-positioning the CSS link higher or lower in the code has effects - though no clear fix.

It would be nice if I could "re-instate" the loaded fonts once the page was complete.

Comment: If you have a question, please post your own question

Answer (score 0):

On our project we identified that web fonts would revert after page load in Internet Explorer when we had the developer tools open.  We still have to remind ourselves of this from time to time, but this is why you might see this odd behavior occur locally but not in production.

It definitely does not happen on every page load, but is more frequent when we manually refresh pages.  We have not found documentation for this behavior but have experienced it on multiple computers when running IE 10 and especially IE 11.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem of flash of styled content and for me, the cause was two-fold:

1. I had the font installed locally
2. I was using the wrong URL for the web-font

So before the webfont loaded, Explorer served up the local version. It then tried to load the font with an incorrect URL, which didn't work, which caused it to fall back to a standard sans-serif font.